# Teams bot, which approach to go for?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

My use case requires me to integrate teams with an app. Whenever a message is sent from that app, a private channel will be created and the message will be sent to teams. I've been reading the documentation and it has only confused me further. Do I need to use graph or bot? Can I do this using only graphs or only bot?

Comment: I'm not sure what "private channel" means - do you mean a new private channel inside a Teams team? See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels

Comment: Also please clarify if you want to send the message to a specific user, privately (i.e. 1-1) or are you wanting these messages to go to a team inside Teams?

Comment: ok got it. To create a totally new channel, you can do *that* part using the Graph API, but NOT via a bot (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). So it sounds like for your app, you'll need to use a bit of both Bot and Graph for certain things.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to send a message using Graph API - see here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

HOWEVER, there are two ways to authenticate with Graph, either via an "application" permission (kind of like background service), or via "delegation", which means your app would work *on behalf of* a user. For this specific Graph endpoint, Microsoft mentions in the page that Application permissions are only allowed for "migration" (e.g. if you were building a tool to migrate from, say, slack to Teams). That means that you would have to use "delegation" which means the message would appear to come *from a specific user*.

As an example, instead of the message coming from "ABC Application", it would appear to come from "Syed Muhammad Ibrahim". If that's ok, then you can use Graph. If not, you would need to go the Bot route.